# String .replace is not working in Android

Tags: android, string

```
String s1=s.replace('"', '\"');
```

here i want to replace `"` with `\"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `String s1 = s.replace("\"", "\\\"");`

*Explanation:*
When referencing a quote or backslash in a string, i.e. anything inside double quotes, a `\` is required to state that you want the quote to appear within the quotes, not end the quotes.  Does this make sense?

For example, you would write `String message = "She said \"Hello\" the other day."`, so that the backslashes represent that the quotes don't actually end the whole string, but are rather to be part of the string.

Comment: Just to add a reference to more escape sequences: [Escape Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1=s.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

It will replace all `"` by `\"`.